# Keystore loading

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I would like to know what's the equivalent in java of the following :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=test JavaFile
```

I would like to load the keystore otherwise than sending it as arguments from the command line. I've been working with :

```
private TcpLink createSSL() {
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
        SSLContext ctx = null;
        SSLSocket socket = null;
        TcpLink smscLink = null;

        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            LOGGER.info("Got keystore");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/root/keystore.jks"), "test".toCharArray());
            LOGGER.info("Loaded keystore");
            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(keyStore);
            LOGGER.info("Inited keystore");
            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("100.100.201.189", 8807);
            LOGGER.info("Got socket");
            smscLink = new TcpLink(socket);

            return smscLink;

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Key store exception : " + e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException : " + e);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            LOGGER.error("CertificateException : " + e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("FileNotFoundException : " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("FileNotFoundException : " + e);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error("KeyManagementException : " + e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception : " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but I get :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1293)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
```

Any ideas are welcome !

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can set the System properties this way:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", '/path/to/keystore.jks');
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", 'your-password-here');
```

They will be used system-wide (in this instance of JVM), so probably you want to do it at initialisation time.

Comment: Getting Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
with those changes

Comment: @Sergiu That's caused by a *truststore* problem. Your truststore doesn't trust the server certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It works using this piece of code :

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf =  
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(this.getCertificateContent(), "test".toCharArray());
kmf.init(keyStore, "test".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf =
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("100.125.100.1", 8775);
```

Comment: There's no point using a keystore in your case, just use `ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null)`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want, here's an API to create SSLSocket and SSLServerSocket easyly:

https://github.com/gpotter2/SSLKeystoreFactories

It does not require any other jars.... just get the files and use them like:

```
SSLSocket s = SSLSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert(ip, port, Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/mykey.jks"), "password")
```

Or:

```
SSLServerSocket s = SSLServerSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert(port, Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/mykey.jks"), "password")
```

That's much easier to use :)